# download sharepoint 365 document using python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I am trying to automate the download of sharepoint office 365 files using Python.
I found the following client
https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client

However my requirement is to use a simple client that uses a clientid and secret to grab a acesses token and then download the file.

If you understand OAuth2 then this flow is called client credential grant.
But when i go through the Python Client in the examples section i see

```
settings.py
settings = {
    'url': 'https://mediadev20.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso',
    'username': 'mattim@mediadev20.onmicrosoft.com',
    'password': 'P@ssw0rd'
}

app_settings = {
    'url': 'https://mediadev20.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso',
    'client_id': '99cbd1a9-ec8d-4e89-96c3-699993089d65',
    'client_secret': 'VMdT8mOurDhsvG8yDnP3yFg',
    'redirect_url': 'https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/'
}
```

My problem is i do not know what to with the redirect_url as mine is a standalone client and there is no redirect_url as such.

Does anyone have a sample code or a pointer on how i can use that library without using redirect_url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that scenario you could consider to grant access via [SharePoint App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs) flow. In the latest version of library the support for *SharePoint App-Only* access has been introduced:

```
AuthenticationContext.acquire_token_for_app(client_id,client_secret)
```

Follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) on how to grant access using SharePoint App-Only, below i will summarize the main points:

- First of all, you need to [setup your app-only principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs#setting-up-an-app-only-principal-with-tenant-permissions)
- Next step is granting permissions to the newly created principal
- Once the principal is created and consented you can use the
  principal's id and secret to request an access as demonstrated below:

Example:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext

app_settings = {
    'url': 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/',
    'client_id': '8efc226b-ba3b-4def-a195-4acdb8d20ca9',
    'client_secret': '',
}

context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=app_settings['url'])
context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=app_settings['client_id'], client_secret=app_settings['client_secret'])

ctx = ClientContext(app_settings['url'], context_auth)
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print("Web site title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))
```

Comment: Hi If you are the author of that excellent library then its time to add this example to the example section :).

Comment: :)) yep, that's me so far, thanks!  Will update documentation and examples

Comment: From where do you import `AuthenticationContext`?